# Fluttrer list of audio players

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator, streaming

A value of type 'StreamSubscription' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'StreamSubscription<void Function()>
how to stop listnenig to stream
in flutter this problem i am facig very lomg time how to overcome from that

Comment: Please add some code.